# How to append the value of a cell to the output in another cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to append the value of a cell into my string output.

Example
I have a dropdown selection of *Apple* and *Oranges* in A1. I want A2 to say *You've picked [input value from A1]*, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called *concatenation* of strings. There are three ways to do this in Google Sheets:

```
A2 ="You've picked" & A1
```

or

```
A2 =concatenate("You've picked", A1)
```

or

```
A2 =concat("You've picked", A1)
```

The difference between `concatenate` and `concat` is that the former accepts any number of strings, while the latter accepts only two. There isn't a reason to use `concat`, I mention it just for completeness.